# Define website language through subdomain or subdirectory (es.example.com or www.example.com/es)

Tags: url, seo

I'm about to launch a multi-lingual website and I have to decide whether to define the site's language through a subdomain or a subdirectory. For example:

**es**.example.com --or-- www.example.com/**es**

In every possible aspect (not only for SEO purposes), what are the implications of using either method? What would be the best practice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`es.example.com` and `en.example.com` are different hosts, while `example.com/es` and `example.com/en` would be on the same host.

Some technologies/softwares/services might consider that different *hosts* correspond to different *sites*. E.g. some search engines might handle different subdomains as different websites.

---

I'd go that way:

If the website structure is the same or very similar for all languages (e.g. all/most pages are translated), go with the language code in the path.

If the website structure might be (or might become) different per language, go with the language code in the subdomain. Also if a user of the Spanish site should not be able to login to the English site and vice-versa.

So, a small company website translated to 3 languages should use the path (because all pages are translated and the information architecture is the same), while a multi-lingual forum should use the subdomain (because all the threads/comments will not be translated).

---

Possibly also to consider: in the future you may want to publish additonal websites on their own subdomain. If you went with the language code in subdomain, this would "pollute" the subdomain level:

- en.example.com
- es.example.com
- blog.example.com (new site)

If you'd want to translate the blog site, too, you'd have sub-subdomains:

- en.example.com
- es.example.com
- en.blog.example.com
- es.blog.example.com

Instead, if you'd used the language code in path, you'd get:

- example.com/en/
- example.com/es/
- blog.example.com/en/
- blog.example.com/es/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I'll follow your recommendation and stay with the language code **in the path**: **a)** My site's structure will remain the same, only language will change, **b)** Users logged in on one language could see the site in another language, **c)** Cookies will be the same no matter the language, and **d)** Your last argument really convinced me: If I want to publish an additional website on a subdomain, the URL will be pretty "ugly", to say the least.